# How to create an instance every n seconds in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, p5.js

I am using the p5.js library to create the Google Dinosaur Game.

I have a constructor function of an "obstacle" and I want to create a new instance of this every N seconds. I can't seem to find a way to do this. At the moment I'm creating 1 obstacle like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    obs[i] = new obstacle(random(800), 200);
}
    for (var i = 0; i < obs.length; i++) {
    obs[i].show();
    obs[i].move();
}
```

I tried using setTimeout and setInterval but then none of them appeared...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one helps. :)

```
let obs = []
let n = 2000
let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    obs.push(new obstacle(random(800), 200)) 
    obs[obs.length-1].show();
    obs[obs.length-1].move();
},n)
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, the issue i had is i forgot to decrease the index by -1 because its an array... lol

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please mark it as completed.